# Select node by value - puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, testing, puppeteer

I have a simple script in which I am trying to test the functionality of some buttons.  Inside of my html I have a button:

```
<button> MyList </button>
```

In my script I tried the following:

```
...
await page.type('button[value="MyList"]');
await page.click('button[value="MyList"]');
```

This was a shot in the dark as I could not find a way to select an element by value in the puppeteer docs.  Obviously it cannot find it and I get the `error:  'No node found for selector: button[value="AccountList"]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the button's value is not `MyList`. `MyList` is the text content of the elment which is different than the `value` which is an attribute. In CSS you cannot query for elements by their text contents. Since there is no such  native CSS selector that will work for your use-case, you have to traverse the DOM manually and look for the matching nodes.

There is such selector implemented in jQuery -
 [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). I guess you can use some similar library for Node.js.